# Das Verb „patentieren"

Tags: verb-usage, legal-terminology

Sind folgende Beispiele korrekte Anwendungen des Verbs *patentieren*?

1. Ich patentiere diese Erfindung.
2. Diese Erfindung wird patentiert.
3. Ich lasse *(mir?)* diese Erfindung patentieren.
4. Diese Erfindung lässt sich patentieren.

Duden hilft mir nicht mit Beispielen dabei.  Ein paar Englisch-Deutsch Wörterbücher zeigen zwei Beiträge für *patentieren*, immer mit *lassen* und einen auch mit *sich*.  Ich konnte mich nicht schlaumachen, wozu das Reflexiv benötigt wird.

Comment: Der Korpus von DWDS liefert ziemlich viele Beispiele: Korpustreffer für "patentieren", aus dem [Kernkorpus des Digitalen Wörterbuchs der deutschen Sprache](<https://www.dwds.de/r/?q=patentieren&corpus=kern&date-start=1900&date-end=1999&genre=Belletristik&genre=Wissenschaft&genre=Gebrauchsliteratur&genre=Zeitung&format=full&sort=date_desc&limit=10>), abgerufen am 27.06.2021

Comment: @guidot Seit langem habe ich nach so etwas gesucht.  Danke vielmals!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Das Verb "patentieren" bedeutet, einen bestimmten Entwurf, Gedanken oder ähnliches mit einem Patent zu versehen (von anderen Schutzarten, etwa Markenschutz oder Geschmacksmusterschutz mal abgesehen):

> **[§ 1 Patentgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/patg/__1.html)**
>
> (1) Patente werden für Erfindungen auf allen Gebieten der Technik erteilt, sofern sie neu sind, auf einer  erfinderischen Tätigkeit beruhen und gewerblich anwendbar sind.
>
> (2) Patente werden für Erfindungen im Sinne von Absatz 1 auch dann erteilt, wenn sie ein Erzeugnis, das aus biologischem Material besteht oder dieses enthält, oder wenn sie ein Verfahren, mit dem biologisches Material hergestellt oder bearbeitet wird oder bei dem es verwendet wird, zum Gegenstand haben. Biologisches Material, das mit Hilfe eines technischen Verfahrens aus seiner natürlichen Umgebung isoliert oder hergestellt wird, kann auch dann Gegenstand einer Erfindung sein, wenn es in der Natur schon vorhanden war.
>
> (3) Als Erfindungen im Sinne des Absatzes 1 werden insbesondere nicht angesehen:
>
> 1. Entdeckungen sowie wissenschaftliche Theorien und mathematische Methoden;
> 2. ästhetische Formschöpfungen;
> 3. Pläne, Regeln und Verfahren für gedankliche Tätigkeiten, für Spiele oder für geschäftliche Tätigkeiten sowie Programme für Datenverarbeitungsanlagen;
> 4. die Wiedergabe von Informationen.
>
> (4) Absatz 3 steht der Patentfähigkeit nur insoweit entgegen, als für die genannten Gegenstände oder Tätigkeiten als solche Schutz begehrt wird.

Wirkung der Patentierung:

> **[§ 9 Patentgesetz](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/patg/__9.html)**
>
> Das Patent hat die Wirkung, dass allein der Patentinhaber befugt ist, die patentierte Erfindung im Rahmen des geltenden Rechts zu benutzen. Jedem Dritten ist es verboten, ohne seine Zustimmung
>
> 1. ein Erzeugnis, das Gegenstand des Patents ist, herzustellen, anzubieten, in Verkehr zu bringen oder zu gebrauchen oder zu den genannten Zwecken entweder einzuführen oder zu besitzen;
> 2. ein Verfahren, das Gegenstand des Patents ist, anzuwenden oder, wenn der Dritte weiß oder es auf Grund der Umstände offensichtlich ist, daß die Anwendung des Verfahrens ohne Zustimmung des Patentinhabers verboten ist, zur Anwendung im Geltungsbereich dieses Gesetzes anzubieten;
> 3. das durch ein Verfahren, das Gegenstand des Patents ist, unmittelbar hergestellte Erzeugnis anzubieten, in Verkehr zu bringen oder zu gebrauchen oder zu den genannten Zwecken entweder einzuführen oder zu besitzen.

Es handelt sich insbesondere um einen Vorgang, den nicht jedermann ausführen kann; vielmehr gibt es dafür eigene Ämter. Aus diesem Grund **ist die aktivische Form "ich patentiere" (Frage Fall 1) praktisch unüblich**, da "Otto Normalverbraucher" nicht selbst ein Patent erteilen kann. Falls einer der seltenen Fälle vorliegt, die die Perspektive des handelnden Beamten wiedergeben, wird eher die formelle Formulierung "ein Patent erteilen" verwendet werden, so dass auch hier die aktivische Form ungebräuchlich ist.

Der **Regelfall** beschreibt vielmehr die Perspektive des Erfinders / Unternehmers, der sich eine Idee schützen *lässt*, der (sich) also ein Patent darauf erteilen *lässt*. Ob man nun das Reflexivpronomen ("sich") dazunimmt, ist eher Stilfrage - so wird m.E. der wirtschaftliche Zweck und Nutzen des Vorgangs betont.

Fazit: Variante 1. wäre theoretisch denkbar, ist aber wohl extrem ungebräuchlich. Varianten 2 bis 4 sind m.E. ok, wobei ich bei 2. über den Präsens stolpere (oder soll das Futur sein?).

Comment: ad 3) Ein Patentanwalt lässt wohl viele Erfindungen patentieren, aber nicht sich, sondern seinen Klienten.

Comment: @userunknown Auf welches 3) in Frage bzw. Antwort bezieht sich Dein Kommentar?

Comment: Sehr gründlich, danke.  In Bezug auf mein 2. Beispiel: ist das nicht Passiv Präsens?  Ich habe etwas ähnliches auf die Wikipedia-Seite gelesen: ,,Damit eine Erfindung patentiert wird..." (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patent)

Comment: @artificial_moonlet: ja, das ist auf jeden Fall grammatikalisch ok und in dieser Fügung auch gebräuchlich.

Comment: Wobei 4 mMn eine andere Bedeutung hat: "diese Erfindung ist patentfähig", also nur, dass auf die Erfindung ein Patent erteilt werden kann und nicht, dass jemand das gerade beabsichtigt oder dabei ist es zu tun - analog zu "das lässt sich machen" mit der Bedeutung von "lassen" nach Duden: die Möglichkeit zu etwas bieten; in bestimmter Weise geeignet sein

Comment: @KritikerderElche: Punkt 3 aus der Frage.